# How can I autospec mock attributes that are None by default in python 3?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest

Consider this code:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, bar=None):
        self.bar = bar

    def methodA(self):
        print("In methodA")

    def methodB(self):
        print("In methodB")


def my_func(bar):
    foo = Foo(bar)
    if foo.bar:
        foo.methodA()
    foo.methodB()


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_my_func(self):
        bar = None

        with patch("__main__.Foo", autospec=True) as foo:
            my_func(bar)
            foo.methodB.assert_called_once_with()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The idea is fairly simple. I have a function whose behavior switches on the presence or absence of an instance attribute. I'm trying to write a unit test that verifies only certain `Foo` methods are executed, depending on the attribute.

Based on the mock library's [patch](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) and [autospeccing](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.mock.html#auto-speccing) docs, I thought setting `autospec=True` in the `patch()` context manager would suffice. It doesn't. The generated `Mock()` correctly includes mocks of `methodA` and `methodB`, but the test fails with this error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_my_func (__main__.MyTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 28, in test_my_func
    my_func(bar)
  File "trash.py", line 18, in my_func
    if foo.bar:
  File "/.../python3.3/unittest/mock.py", line 549, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("Mock object has no attribute %r" % name)
AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'bar'
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't seem to figure out what. How can I unittest `my_func()`?

Answer (score 2):

Part of my problem was a misunderstanding of patch's behavior. The context manager I set up is returning an instance of the `__main__.Foo` mock, not the *same instance* used in `my_func()`. To put it another way, even when I was able to mock `Foo` properly, without autospec, I couldn't execute `assert_called_once_with()` over any of its methods: It wasn't the same object.

One solution is to mock the method itself. This works:

```
def test_my_func(self):
    bar = None
    with patch('__main__.Foo.methodB') as mock_methodB:
        my_func(bar)
        mock_methodB.assert_called_once_with()
```

Another method would be modifying `my_func()` to return foo:

```
def my_func(bar):
    foo = Foo(bar)
    if foo.bar:
        foo.methodA()
    foo.methodB()
    return foo
```

Because the function returns the mock under test, the following should work:

```
def test_my_func(self):
    bar = None
    with patch('__main__.Foo', spec=True, bar=None):
        foo = my_func(bar)
        assert foo.methodB.called
        assert not foo.methodA.called
```